# How to use the takeWhile function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

There's a mixin for underscore which has a `takeWhile` function, you can see it [here](https://gist.github.com/1222480), and [here](https://github.com/JosephMoniz/UnderscoreKit/blob/master/underscorekit.js) (I'm using this one).

How do you use this?

`takeWhile: function(list, callback, context)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use it like so...

```
var newArr = _.takeWhile([1, 2, 3, 2, 1], function(elem) {
     return elem < 3;
}); // [1, 2]
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/itofuc/edit#preview).

Comment: Can you do declare a function somewhere and do: _.takeWhile(arr, aFunction(arr))

Comment: @LeilaHamon That will execute `aFunction(arr)` and use its return value as the argument. You probably just want to pass the reference, e.g. `aFunction` (the first argument will be the array element, not the array, which is the third).